# Run one test file with jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Installed jest:

```
yarn add jest
```

Add a file in ./src/index.js with the content:

```
test('First test', () => {
  expect(true).toBe(true);
});
```

Try to run it with:

```
node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js src/index.js
```

or

```
node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js ./src/index.js
```

But all I get is:

```
No tests found
In /home/me/dev/lib
  7 files checked.
  testMatch: **/__tests__/**/*.js?(x),**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x) - 0 matches
  testPathIgnorePatterns: /node_modules/ - 7 matches
Pattern: ./src/index.js - 0 matches
```

Just would like to run the one file without having to go through the pain of setting up a directory convention or config file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Jest's website

> Place your tests in a `__tests__` folder, or name your test files with a .spec.js or .test.js extension. Whatever you prefer, Jest will find and run your tests.

You can see in the test match

> `testMatch: **/__tests__/**/*.js?(x),**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x) - 0 matches`

It is looking for files that are .spec or .test and end in .js or .jsx

Comment: I used the naming convention and it worked. The documentation here: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/cli.html mentions `jest path/to/my-test.js` as I've tried but that doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
import LoggerService from '../LoggerService ';

describe('Method called****', () => {
  it('00000000', () => {
    const logEvent = jest.spyOn(LoggerService , 'logEvent');
    expect(logEvent).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

npm test -- **tests**/LoggerService .test.ts -t '00000000'